# How can I update a module with a custom field? In Odoo 9

Tags: inheritance, odoo, odoo-9

I want to add a new field in a model. I create it in the python file and then I am going to show it in the view form:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
  <record id="view_order_form_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">view.order.form.extend</field>
  <field name="model">sale.order</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale_stock.view_order_form_inherit_sale_stock"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
  <xpath expr="//field[@name='picking_policy']" position="after">
    <field name="my_new_field"/>
  </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

When I install the module for the first time, the field appears and everything works fine. The problem comes when I try to update the module.

It gives an exception that says that field `product_tmpl_id` doesn't exist.

How can it be possible? The first installation worked fine...

Note: If I uninstall the module, and then I install it again, it works fine. But then, when I try to update, it shows the error again...

Comment: I do not see the field on the [form you are inheriting](https://github.com/OCA/OCB/blob/9.0/addons/sale/sale_view.xml#L126). Make sure you are inheriting the form where the field appears

Comment: @ChesuCR I have edited the original post with the correct inherit_id.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the xpath just simply use field tag.

For example,

```
<field name="picking_policy" position="after">
    <field name="my_new_field"/>
</field>
```

Also just check your depends in manifest though. Don't forget to put upvote and tickmark this answer.

Comment: I know the field tag option instead of xpath, but this doesn't fix the problem.